# Will the Hydra finally die?

Tags: code-golf, number, game

#### Background

A Medusa have released a dangerous Hydra which is revived unless the exact number of heads it have is removed. The knights can remove a certain number of heads with each type of attack, and each attack causes a specific amount of heads to regrow. **The knights have hired you to write a program or function that returns a [truthy/falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) depending on whether the Hydra can be left with *exactly* zero heads *after* the next hit.**

<sup>Note that this is fundamentally different from [Become the Hydra Slayer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/137980/become-the-hydra-slayer). You are not supposed to figure out which attacks to use.</sup>

*For example:*

```
input: head = 2, 
       attacks = [1, 25, 62, 67], 
       growths = [15, 15, 34, 25], 
       hits = [5, 1, 0, 0]
output: TRUE
```

*Explanation:* The Hydra has 10 heads to start with, we have 4 different `attacks` and for each attack, `growth` gives us the number of heads that grows back. `hits` gives us the number of times each attack is applied. So the number of heads the Hydra has after each attack is

```
2 -> 16 -> 30 -> 44 -> 58 -> 72 -> 62
```

Since `62` is a valid attack value (It lies in the attack list), we return `True` since the Hydra will die on the next attack (be left with 0 heads). Note that the order for when the attacks are done is irrelevant.

```
2 -> 16 -> 6 -> 20 -> 34 -> 48 -> 62
```

---

#### Input

Any sort of logical way of feeding your program the attack, regrowth and hit values are acceptable. This includes, but is not limited to

- A list of tuples `(1, 15, 5), (25, 15, 1) (62, 34, 0) (67, 25, 0)`
- Lists `2, [1, 25, 62, 67], [15, 15, 34, 25], [5, 1, 0, 0]`
- Reading values from STDIN `1 15 1 15 1 15 1 15 1 15 25 15`
- A file of values

---

#### Output

- Some form of [truthy/falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) value in your language: 0/1, true/false, etc.

---

#### Assumption

- You may assume that any input is valid. E.g every input will not overkill the Hydra and either result in a number of heads that is an attack value, or not.
- Every list (if used) is to be assumed to be of equal lengths
- Every attack value will always correspond to one regrowth value which never changes. these are not required to be unique
- Every input will be a positive integer

---

#### Test Cases

The following 10 examples are all `True`, and uses `attacks=[1, 25, 62, 67]`, `growths=[15, 15, 34, 25]` these are simply left out to be brief

```
1, [0, 0, 0, 0], -> True
2, [5, 1, 0, 0], -> True
3, [2, 3, 0, 0], -> True
4, [7, 4, 0, 0], -> True
5, [4, 6, 0, 0], -> True
6, [4, 0, 0, 0], -> True
7, [1, 2, 0, 0], -> True
8, [6, 3, 0, 0], -> True
9, [3, 5, 0, 0], -> True
10, [8, 6, 0, 0] -> True
25, [0, 0, 0, 0], -> True
67, [0, 0, 0, 0], -> True
62, [0, 0, 0, 0], -> True
98767893, [0, 1, 1, 2351614] -> True
```

The following examples are all `False`, and uses `attack=[1, 25, 62, 67]`, `growth=[15, 15, 34, 25]` these are simply left out to be brief

```
65, [0, 3, 0, 0], -> False
66, [4, 5, 0, 0], -> False
68, [0, 2, 0, 0], -> False
69, [0, 1, 1, 0], -> False
70, [2, 5, 0, 0], -> False
71, [0, 0, 0, 1], -> False
72, [0, 0, 0, 0], -> False
73, [1, 2, 1, 0], -> False
74, [2, 3, 0, 0], -> False
75, [1, 5, 0, 0], -> False
98767893, [1, 1, 1, 2351614] -> False
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with fewer bytes being better.

Comment: Just remove the heart.

Comment: Are only regrowth values not guaranteed to be unique, or are attack values not necessarily unique as well?

Comment: @att Neither Attack nor regrowth values are necessarily unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
-*∑+c
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=-*%E2%88%91%2Bc&inputs=%5B1%2C%2025%2C%2062%2C%2067%5D%0A%5B15%2C%2015%2C%2034%2C%2025%5D%0A%5B5%2C%201%2C%200%2C%200%5D%0A2&header=&footer=)

Inputs: attacks, growths, hits, heads

### Explanation

`-` subtract: growths - attacks
`*` multiply: that * hits
`∑` sum
`+` add: that + heads
`c` contains: is it in attacks?

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 44 bytes

```hs
w=zipWith
(u#z)y=elem=<<sum.(u:).w(*)z.w(-)y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxCoAgFADQvWvU4I9fpGVB5DkaxKFBSNKQSiIvby6Pt2/3oa1N6RXR@NU8e0FCGeET2monluUOriVhhvYlNcRsA19ymzmFv8z5VISVkiPFDjsFkuZy7AdkXEmaxZHhOKn0Aw)

Pretty simple.  We get the differences of the attacks and the regrows with `zipWith(-)`, then we multiply these by the attacks taken `zipWith(*)z`.  Then we sum that with the starting head count, and check if that is in the attack list.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 56 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZPRboMgFIbvfQoudTtNBES0Sa@W7Al213nBMq0mrTVKk@rLOyi6aQfRoET88vsf@E/Ty/Ja07E4fI5ncfn6FqgEASeQ@/K1u1384cW/7/qguLboDj0MqKrRUDX@SVEyCNSbGGXeyTfR5R06oKOH1HVEGNQjhHmgDNBHe8vVPAFEAww0aAcoGIq6gEgDHPRsBxgYKnYB8QQ4TXIwpRAXkICRcZpMwZTCXAAOweg4XRK2tZcx3yTIFpEmPOZJSicOPwahDMeYWfRmT4vC38W5WyLz7jI3kkwqxI2kK0M2hIdTUtw/4us4Yhti2aFnhP7FweUl@p/aZ4RNKk67i6PA65OIZlahmefprixBQqu78rcL9w@Vpq1q6Rd@aVR0iHQIYp7pBd146qaR/qJWZABtMP4A)

```python
lambda h,a,g,t:h+sum(z*(x-y)for x,y,z in zip(g,a,t))in a
```

Comment: In your TIO link you should put the tests in the footer and the naming of your function in the header like [so](https://tio.run/##hZPRboMgFIbvfQoudTtNBES0Sa@W7Al213nBMq0mrTVKk@rLOyi6aQfRoET88vsf@E/Ty/Ja07E4fI5ncfn6FqgEASeQ@/K1u1384cW/7/qguLboDj0MqKrRUDX@SVEyCNSbGGXeyTfR5R06oKOH1HVEGNQjhHmgDNBHe8vVPAFEAww0aAcoGIq6gEgDHPRsBxgYKnYB8QQ4TXIwpRAXkICRcZpMwZTCXAAOweg4XRK2tZcx3yTIFpEmPOZJSicOPwahDMeYWfRmT4vC38W5WyLz7jI3kkwqxI2kK0M2hIdTUtw/4us4Yhti2aFnhP7FweUl@p/aZ4RNKk67i6PA65OIZlahmefprixBQqu78rcL9w@Vpq1q6Rd@aVR0iHQIYp7pBd146qaR/qJWZABtMP4A "Python 3 – Try It Online"). Good answer though :)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 36 bytes

```r
function(H,a,g,h)sum(H,g*h-a*h)%in%a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLNisIwFEb3PkVQhEau0PynC7fDPIDL2YQybQWtoPb5a9IZm7mTSEsCJeck/Xpzb2NzGJuhrx@na198goMWOnofLv693XV7t@vo9tRv3ejIgdQFA8IVEM39NHTV/iz6lTCFDJSumqA5IC14WAL5HZRuyPE2fHvOIw97Ey4i96pIuIzcAJEJV5F7qBOuEU/zmcjDHyfcRq5z@arIPVQJZ2UUbC4gVwsV1GZJ4AtCZY02thJIY9PgQjHN5CzX7lGs96/nq1@HO9Y44p8ifLjzfYqAy6wyhkVn8IxRZfIhw5SoWTJfMbl2ZMh4W6zZEP9bIskh3zXtbCh0RiZpeicscyeTPT4B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
_ḋ⁵⁶+e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@4Y7uR41bHzVu0079//9/tKGpjgIIG5voKBiZxgIFQLSOgpkREJsD@QZAeTAyMjY1NDM0if1vaWFuZm5haQwA)

Takes four arguments: growths, attacks, hits, heads.

### Explanation

```
_ḋ⁵⁶+e Main dyadic link
_      Subtract: growths - attacks
 ḋ     Dot product with
  ⁵      third argument: hits
    +  Add
   ⁶     fourth argument: heads
     e Is it an element of the second argument: attacks?
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54 bytes

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
(a,g,n,h)=>a.includes(h.map((v,i)=>n+=v*=g[i]-a[i])|n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZPPboQgEMbvPgVHbFmziIIeaLKnfQjigbiua2NxU1tPfXc7omn6TyABSYYfM1/mG5/1pMf6tbu/HcxwaearnLEmLTHkFssnnXSm7t8vzYhvyYu@YzyRDuLmUU4PslVdddDwiT9MPJ@QRIoSlOYE8RS2qKKzjUFg2SxbLqsoqgczDn2T9EOLr/hE0BkAgtSRoG1VcfwvBWlVbmEXxYBK7eGiQI0S9nBRUE0Bwt0UXymPeqhmG@SmCqC4V30JFLPyXBSFS1V45S@WBXSfizAsDcLKQnBRlGyFqV0pyymn2e8nO3U21Z5O8c0cT6t4sWbzuMPL73r3rT6uM@gpKn6MPd3Fwjoq2NeAObVlQf@HyNdsebCN9K@N8yc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
FreeQ[#,#3-#4.(#-#2)]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZLfa4MwEMff/SskjtHCOepvpbRssBb2tq19y/LgxG6CVbEpFMS/3V0aGZWkkEDuPrn73l1yTPlvfkx5kaXDYTVs2zz/oBZYnm35TzPLttw5exxea2p0BdT9qiyqfGl0KXz3q329uTRtfjoVdfW8421R/eyasuBUnj/zpkyznBbQEUrsNekImISJU096BsIC02VL4x2vc3qgnYN2AGbo4o56MDsHLbE9XxD0oDBGmjMCNZA5YQZ0oiSQkpsLb9OM04dd1hYNf6uaM5cEyFeFyi9lKXTttSkN1rMBRekCzHGxK92359zAKqjQV4CHAKGnAKySRmD6CsA0FL2hAkIJVHFMQ8U4FBAjCHXiCQL0Bgpw0KaxTl0MW997GN0l7j2SxFEYxYknuXNdrhc4oePfxo@akwa2aXlCNE4j0KBYRrkalNwKTlC0kC@lSRhNnt2ZIF2HI/L@n0XR8jW/YkSBjNKUcTMzRzuz67U/)

Input `[attacks, growths, hits, head]`. Returns `True` if the hydra cannot be slain on the next hit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
№η⁺θΣＥε×ι⁻§ζκ§ηκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5vxRIZugoBOSUFmsU6igEl@Zq@CYWaKTqKIRk5qYWa2TqKPhm5gElHUs881JSKzSqdBSyNXUUYNwMEBcKrP//jzbSUYg21FEwMtVRMAOyzcxjQQJAHggbm4BkQCIgAR0FAyCKjf2vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs one `-` for each matching attack, so if there are two attacks that deal the same amount of damage then `--` will be output. Explanation:

```
      ε             Array of hits
     Ｅ              Map over elements
          §ζκ       Relevant growth
         ⁻          Subtract
             §ηκ    Relevant attack
       ×            Multiplied by
        ι           Current element
    Σ               Take the sum
  ⁺θ                Add the starting number of heads
№η                  Output the number of matching attacks
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

Just to remind myself that `/` supports cycling gerunds. Takes health on the left, (hits, regrow, attack) on the right.

```
(+1#.*`-/)e.2{]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdM7jsIwEAbgfk8xWorwSELG70SiQqLaanskJARCNByAw4cfB0EoYCaJXSSfnRmPfe5/6@JIq44KKqmhDq2qaf3/t@mnC57U8121nB1qc932s5/D/nQhpiNQvkv2hMc6Mr7sGD0FQyEO0ADiuwwtoEEvQgcY0YvQAzoKMgwZKpKJgHgnwwQYNMm0gBaRipAbyKTJxnhtbUJUS6OVbYohptZmz/fVsp4Du@@jigpX8fjXEP@wePQ9rKFyXkNTntVoaPsMXqKxybtWE0B8HRmW6Hi1BWofW1IRqxudMIH6PKsmrVG9@a3en4b1Nw)

- `` *`-/ `` Does hits * regrow - attack
- `1#.` summed
- `+` plus health
- `e.2{]` exists in the attacks?